# Recording quickest time in python.

Tags: python, timer

Basically I want to record high scores in my program. I'm new to coding so need a bit of help. I will create this basic program to demonstrate what I want.

```
import time

name = input("Please enter your name: ")
mylist=["Man utd are the best team","I am going to be a pro typer.","Coding is really fun when you can do it."]
x=random.choice (mylist)
print ("The sentence I would like you to type is: ")
print (x)

wait = input ("Please press enter to continue, The timer will start upon hitting enter!")
start = time.time()
sentence = input("Start typing: ")
end = time.time()
overall = end - start

if sentence == (x):
    print ("It took you this many seconds to complete the sentence: %s" % overall)
    if overall <= 9:
        print ("Nice job %s" % name)
        print ("You have made it to level 2!")
```

How would I be able to save the time it took and if someone beats the time make that the new high score?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a way to persist data across program executions. There are many ways to do it, but the simplest is [just writing to a file](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open).

In addition, if you want to use a database, look into [SQLite3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html) for Python.